# Getting cannot find \node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress error after install npm faker

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, faker

After installing npm faker in my cypress project, I get the following error when trying to run cypress. I cannot see the cypress inside  \node_modules\cypress\bin\ folder.

Do I need to install cypress again or do anyone know how to resolve this, please?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Repo\ParcelManagementPortalUserApp\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Reinstalling is easy-peasy, but you should try to figure out why it happed. Generally, there is no effect between two installs, you must have done something to cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there were some errors when the installation. Reinstall the yarn and issue resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).